# The best way to merge with Beans and Play Java

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am trying to use Play 2.3.x for a small project. I am used to 1.2.x, and am struggling to understand some of the changes.

One of the changes is the use of EBeans and forms. This worked very well in 1.2.x but I don't understand quite how to do this in 2.3.x

I have controller:

```
package controllers;

import models.Device;
import play.data.DynamicForm;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.util.List;

public class Devices extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        List<Device> devices = Device.find.all();
        return ok(views.html.Devices.index.render(devices));
    }

    public static Result add () {
        Form<Device> myForm = Form.form(Device.class);
        return ok(views.html.Devices.add.render(myForm));
    }

    public static Result edit(Long id){
        Device device = Device.find.byId(id);
        Form<Device> myForm = Form.form(Device.class);
        myForm = myForm.fill(device);

        return ok(views.html.Devices.edit.render(myForm));
    }

    public static Result update() {
        Device device = Form.form(Device.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        device.update();
        return index();
    }
}
```

I can add a Device, and want to edit it. This is the template:

```
@(myForm: Form[Device])

@main("Edit a device") {

  @helper.form(action = routes.Devices.update()) {
    @helper.inputText(myForm("name"))
    @helper.inputText(myForm("ipAddress"))
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  }

  <a href="@routes.Devices.index()">Cancel</a>
}
```

But how do I merge the changes with the object already stored? Is there an easy way, or do I have find the object and then go through the object field by field manually? In 1.2.x (with JPA) there was the merge() option which took care of all that. I would use JPA, but default support as in 1.2.x does not seem that strong.

Now I get (understandably):

```
[OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated [0] rows sql[update device set name=?, ip_address=?, last_update=? where id=?] bind[null]]
```

Comment: Publish the project to github pls, I'll check it (just assume that's general testing project w/out credentials yet)

Comment: I posted it on https://github.com/luukjansen/temperature-control.

Comment: (the form in question is http://localhost:9000/devices/ where one can be added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Optimistic lock is caused in your case by missing `id` value in your form, you're on good track with id in edit form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@myForm("id")">
```

Anyway correct code is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@myForm("id").value">
```

Two tips:

1. You can set a breakpoint in Idea - so in debug mode you could recognize that `id` of the bound `device` is null.
2. While using constraints on your fields you should also handle errors in your action

Correctly it can be something like this, also see at the end how to redirect to the index after successful update:

```
public static Result update() {
    Form<Device> deviceForm = Form.form(Device.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (deviceForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(views.html.Devices.edit.render(deviceForm, listOfRoles()));
    }

    // Form is OK, has no errors, we can proceed
    Device device = deviceForm.get();
    device.update(device.id);
    return redirect(routes.Devices.index());
}
```

`listOfRoles()` is just wrapped code from your `edit()` action:

```
private static List<String> listOfRoles(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(DeviceRole role : DeviceRole.values()) {
        list.add(role.toString());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: That works perfect! Now the enum, as it trows "Invalid property 'roles[0]'" but I post that as a different question.

Comment: I'd suggest to use ManyToMany relation for this